# Should I design with MDBootstrap or Material 2 in designing a responsive app for all platforms

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have been recently designing a basic site and learning angular 2.
I have created a basic site (navbar, landing page, 404) with Angular 2 Material ( https://material.angular.io/ ) and its fine although im having alot of trouble with making it correctly responsive with window size.

Is MD Bootstrap ( https://mdbootstrap.com ) a better solution currently because Material 2 is still in heavy development or is Material 2 what I should get used to in creating modern web applications and becoming the industry standard.

I am open to whatever and dont have any bias with what 'should be used' according to company or brand loyalty, I just want to know as a web developer pretty new to Angular 2 web app design what would be the best to learn for me and for my future in webdev?
Thanks!

**Side note** [Why should I start using Google Material Design Lite instead of Twitter Bootstrap or Foundation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31391643/why-should-i-start-using-google-material-design-lite-instead-of-twitter-bootstra?rq=1) I read through this and its information and answers are outdated? It seems that MDBootstrap supports Typescript, angular 2 and no jquery as of now so should i not even bother with Material 2 for the time being?

Any feedback is greatly appreciated for a new programmer like myself :)

Comment: MD Boostrap seems to be somewhat limited if you go with the free version - just take a look at how many components are marked as "MDB Pro Component".

Answer (score 2):

All these frameworks you mentioned will serve you. This fight for which framework to use is 70% personal preference. I would advice you go for anyone that has enough user base and has been tested and trusted, because when you need help(don't we all need help), the number of people using it will come into play for your advantage.

Apart from that, pick the one you fancy and throw shades to your friends about using something else. LOL.